# Print Data from JSON Array in Template from Component

Tags: arrays, json, angular

Here is My API Call and getting response in this.order.info

```
this.http.get(this.order_info_url+'/'+this.order_id)
.subscribe(
   response => {
      this.order_info =  response.json();
      console.log(this.order_info[0]);
    },
    error => {
       alert(error.text());
       return error.text();
    }
);
```

And My Response is

```
{
  "table1": [
    {
      "store_name": "Your Store",
      "store_url": "http://localhost:8080/upload/",
      "date_added": "2016-11-18T07:51:53.000Z",
      "payment_method": "Cash On Delivery",
      "shipping_method": "Flat Shipping Rate",
      "firstname": "q",
      "lastname": "q",
      "Customer_Group_Name": "Default",
      "email": "q@g.com"      
    }
  ],
  "table2": [
    {
      "Customer_Notified": "NO",
      "date_added": "2016-11-18T07:51:54.000Z",
      "comment": "",
      "name": "Pending"
    }
  ]
}
```

How I get table1.store_name in my template from component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get that value like this:

```
<p>{{ order_info?.table1[0].store_name }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much You Saved my lots of time!